# Inserting datetime NOW() in database with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert date when user make registration but doesn't work. It didn't insert anything when I add `NOW()` to the query. If I remove it user is added into database.

This is normal query

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':active' => $activasion
));
```

I've read other threads and tried this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,created,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, NOW(), :active');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':active' => $activasion
));
```

just added `created` and `NOW()` to the query but didn't insert anything.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Why don't use "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()" on your column ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing closing parenthesis on the SQL you are feeding to `prepare()`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,created,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, NOW(), :active');
```

It should be

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,created,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, NOW(), :active)');
```

As @VincentDecaux suggests, your error checking should catch this. Use the following to enable exceptions, if that's what you prefer:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was in closing parenthesis. Thank's for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try ths

```
$created = date("Y:m:d h:i:s");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,created,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :created, :active');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':active' => $activasion,
    ':created' => $created
));
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to catch your error :

```
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,created,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, NOW(), :active');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => $hashedpassword,
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':active' => $activasion
    ));
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Then, you can use this way :

```
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
    ':created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ':email'   => $_POST['email'],
    ':active'  => $activasion
));
```

Comment: It didn't get any errors. I've got the message that user creation is success but didn't write into database. Tried to echo errors.. but none

Comment: Ok i catch the error - `PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`.. but why? As I understand I don't need to pass parameter for `NOW()`?